# Multiple mails to same receipt through AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

I have cron server in which we are calling a cron job that contacts another server to fetch data and send emails (through **AWS SES**).

The Issue is it is sending multiple emails even though cron job is executing only once.

For testing, I have created a local cron server that fetches data from the live server and it sends e-mail through our own SMTP then it is working fine. (i.e. sending mail once). I am confused where can be the issue.

Comment: Can we see the code of the cron job?

Comment: share the contab and email logs please

Comment: I will be sharing detail in a minute. But one more thing we tried, i.e. replacing client emails with our emails make it work ok. That's strange. Does that mean there is some issue at client emails ?

Comment: Hi @d1ll1nger, my crontab is 45 8 * * 1 wget <url>